# is it possible to downgrade c3.large to m3.medium?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I have c3.large reserved instance and want to downgrade it to m3.medium. Is it possible to downgrade without any downtime please advise.

Comment: Off-topic; belongs on [sf]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks ! I have collected the information now the right one !
http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/

- Q: Can I reassign my Reserved instance from one instance type (e.g., c1.xlarge) to another (e.g., m1.large)?
- No. A Reserved instance is associated with a specific instance family for the duration of its term; however, you can change from one instance type (e.g., c3.large) to another (e.g., c3.xlarge) in the same family, if it is a Linux/UNIX Reserved instance

Comment: You can re-size the instance. But you would need to stop the instance first. The reservation however, would no longer apply to the instance and you would be continue to pay for the reservation until you sell it.